# What are the oddly named devices in the Google Play Developer Console?

Tags: android, google-play

I was looking at the statistics for an app i just published on the Play Store, and among the standard devices (like Samsung Galaxy, Nexus 4, etc.) were a number of devices with what look like custom names. One, for example, is just named "vanquish".

What is the deal with these? Just custom named phones or something else?

Comment: looks like the types of names that some carriers/manufacturers give to their devices before the consumer marketed name of the device is settled on. Sometimes these names get leftover in the `Build` static variables on the device which is probably what the market is using to populate that list.

Comment: Don't know why my question got closed, seems relevant to software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the internal names used by the manufacturers!

Comment: Thanks for the answers thiagolr and FoamyGuy!